# angularjs communicate betweend controllers

Tags: angularjs, controller

I'm new in Angular. I have a problem with communicate between controller.

Page layout is like this:

```
------------------------------------
page header "play" 00:00:00 (TimeController)

------------------------------------

page content <br><br>
ng-view  

(TaskController)<br><br>
ul>li<br>
- "play" link task 1<br>
- "play" link task 2<br>
- "play" link task 3<br>
```

So I have two controllers `TimeController` and `TaskController`. TimeController has a timer in page header.

List of tasks is in rounting view/tasks-list.html

```
    app.config(['$routeProvider', function($routeProvider) {
        $routeProvider.
            when('/', {
                templateUrl: 'views/tasks-list.html',
                controller: 'TaskController'
            }).
```

The "play" is a button. When i click on it i need to run a function from TimeController.   Also click on "play" in header should run the same function from TimeController.

I dont know how to do this.

Comment: This does not ask a specific question

Comment: this seems like a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18482488/angularjs-using-service-to-communicate-between-controllers but it's hard to tell for sure.

Answer (score 0):

Use events. Something like $rootScope.$emit("doSomething"); in the task controller and in the time controller use something like

```
$rootScope.$on("doSomething", function () {
//event triggered
});
```