# How to assign object in factory - angularjs

Tags: angularjs

If I assign an object in a factory like this:

```
$http.get('/api/whatever').success(function(data) {
  result = data.obj
});
```

It gives result a new address and therefore the reference from my controller to the `result` is broken.
How to assign it then? Value by value works, but seems not the right way. How to watch an object properly?

Comment: Quick and dirty ~ `angular.extend(result, data.obj)`

Comment: I generally recommend that you return a promise from the service. Then you can resolve the promise in the controller and grab the value.

Comment: Do you mean you are sharing a global `result` variable between your factory and controller? *Outch*

Answer (score 0):

Basically factory has get and set methods for getting and setting the value in factory object.
[Here is the example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29769804/getting-and-setting-value-in-factory-in-angualrjs/29771721#29771721). Some time you may have to use events after updating the factory object so all others instance have updated value